# How to add vertical scrollbar to NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to make a command window(user types in text) and need to put in place a scrollbar, to look back at what was typed, on the NSTextField. thx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`NSTextField` is usually used only for one line text so You need to use `NSTextView` instead `NSTextField` to achieve scrolling.

[NSTextView Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstextview_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[image: TextView]

Comment: More precisely, you need to use an NSTextView inside an NSScrollView. The one in Xcode's Object Library is already so configured, but if you create the text view in code, you need to put it into a scroll view yourself.